# What is the right way to persist a DataFrame to a database

Tags: sql, pandas

What is the right way to persist a DataFrame to a database using custom SQL code? The `DataFrame.apply()` function executes the `save_entity()` function with the custom SQL code TWICE for the first row of the DataFrame that is not acceptable. The code below illustrates the problem

```
# save_entity() is executed TWICE for the first row
entities_df["entity_id"] = entities_df.apply(save_entity, axis=1)
```

I'm preferable looking for a declarative approach for working with a DataFrame as a whole, rather then using lower-level `DataFrame.iterrows()` or `DataFrame.itertuples()` functions that do not produce a DataFrame any more.

Comment: Are you trying to store the entire DataFrame to a SQL database? If so, I recommend reviewing pandas.to_sql() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: I prefer to have complete control over the SQL to persist a DataFrame row and I'd avoid using SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas `DataFrame.to_sql()` method. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: The `DataFrame.to_sql()` limits the solution to only the databases supported my SQLAlchemy. I'd like to have a complete control over the SQL to persist a DataFrame row.

Comment: I think I want something very simple, but it seems that Pandas does not have it. I want a `DataFrame.map(func)` function that applies other `process_row(row)` function to each row of the DataFrame and allows to store the return values from the `process_row(row)` function as a new column in the initial DataFrame. I want a DataFrame as input and I want a DataFrame as output with the logic applied in between for each row.